# Almacenar imagen transparente indexada en un BufferedImage

Tags: java, imagen, bufferedimage

Por favor necesito saber cómo puedo crear un `BufferedImage` que almacene una imagen transparente con color `indexado` de 256x256 píxeles.

Por favor si alguien me puede iluminar con esta duda les agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

Comment: Cuando hablas de "color indexado", a que te refieres?

Answer (score 0):

Con la funcion que te voy a compartir, puedes cargar alguna imagen de tus recursos de tu proyecto JAVA y darle el tamaño que desees:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public Image obtenerImagen(String rutaImagen, int alto, int ancho) throws IOException{
    BufferedImage perfil = null;
    Image imagen = null;
    try{
        perfil = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(rutaImagen));
        imagen = perfil.getScaledInstance(alto, ancho, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    }catch(IOException e){
        perfil = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("assets/FotoErrorOporDefecto.png"));
        imagen = perfil.getScaledInstance(alto, ancho, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    }
    return imagen;
}
```

*Como lo usarias?... por ejemplo:*

```
JLabel example = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(obtenerImagen("/assets/chichas.png",250,250)));
```

Solo asegurate de crear un paquete adicional (puedes llamarlo assets, como se suele hacer) dentro del proyecto, y guardes todas tus imagenes ahi.

Answer (score 0):

Basta especificar el tipo de imagen

```
BufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType)
```

*width*, y *height* son medidas en pixeles independientenmente de la representación interna (ej. dos pixeles podrían ser enpaquetados en un mismo byte), *imageType* es el tipo de imagen, *Java* [soporta imágenes de tipo indexado](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED)

> public static final int TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED
>
> Represents an indexed byte image. When this type is used as the
>   imageType argument to the BufferedImage constructor that takes an
>   imageType argument but no ColorModel argument, an IndexColorModel is
>   created with a 256-color 6/6/6 color cube palette with the rest of the
>   colors from 216-255 populated by grayscale values in the default sRGB
>   ColorSpace.

Así que para crear una BufferedImage de 256x256

```
BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED)
```